# How to integrate a jar application into a web application when the package name is not known?

Tags: java, applet, integration

I am developing one web application in PHP/HTML and I need to integrate one java applet software (`.jar`).

**Jar Application**: `source.jar`

I found one tutorial for integration

https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/applets.html

but it needs to have the package name to be known. In my case I don't have access to its package as it is a open source software (already packaged).

How can I integrate this application into my web application?

Comment: Avoid using Applets, ever, because they're awful. Security vulnerabilities, slow, clunky, and generally just bad. See if you can duplicate the functionality using JS and HTML.

Comment: I edited the the title to better reflect your question and did minor edits to the question for better readability.

Comment: Applets would just live as files in your web application.  Applets aren't actually run on an app server, but rather from the client side.

Comment: Of course you have access to the package  name. Just read the documentation.

Comment: *"..it is a open source software.."*  Link to the source code.  But as mentioned by @EJP, there should also be documentation for it (and if not, then it is **not** something that should be put into any web app.).

Comment: I can just see its output on

Comment: Its a applet tool and i can use it standalone but now i need to integrate it in my tool.